# Can't Create A Scaffold using Rails - No password error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I m having trouble creating a scaffold with rails

I was following a tutorial when I ran into the following problem.

```
rails new SuperAwesomeApp -d postgresql
rails g scaffold item name:string description:text
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/
connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1216:
in `initialize': fe_sendauth: no password supplied (PG::Error)
```

How do I supply rails / postgres with a password?

Still pretty new to rails, so I appreciate the help.

Comment: See [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#configuring-a-postgresql-database) how to "Configuring a PostgreSQL Database"

Comment: Ok, I will check that, I am surprised that my tutorial did not inform me about this @LuísRamalho

Comment: What's the tutorial you're following?

Comment: http://www.codeschool.com/code_tv/rails-app-from-scratch-part-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open up you `config/database.yml`. You are probably missing a password required to access the database here. Example of database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: database_name
  host: 10.0.0.1
  port: 1433
  username: username
  password: passsword
```

Comment: I am using the password I used for previous Python projects, but I still get a FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "MyUsername" ,  I wish the tutorial would explain what to do. This looks like a good answer, I will accept it once, I've got everything sorted out

Comment: Decided to just use SQLite locally, and let Heroku take care of Postgres, since Rails is database-agnostic

Answer (score -1):

Another thing that you really need to tell is the host. If it is localhost, then in your config/database.yml, include;

```
    host: localhost
```

Comment: Anyone care to elaborate on why this was voted down? Y'all know, for posterity? (or at least for future error-Googling newbies...) This question is one of the first hits on Google for similar issues.